# Not able to get data when NEXT is clicked in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code:

```
package working;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        openBrowser();
        System.out.println(scrape());
        closeBrowser();
    }

    private static String table = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[1]";
    private static String tr = table + "/tbody/tr";
    private final static String next = table + "/preceding::a[text()='Next'][1]";
    private final static String yesGotIt = "//body/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-banner \")]/div/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-button-wrapper \")]/button";

    private static String scrape() throws Exception {
        WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
        List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

        int count = 1;
        String rows = "";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(yesGotIt)).click();
        while(count <= 3) {
            for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) {
                List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
                    rows += tdElement.getText() + "\t";
                }
                rows = rows + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(rows);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click();
            count += driver.findElements(By.xpath(next)).size();
            System.out.println(count);
        }
        return rows;
    }

    private static void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "E:\\eclipse-workspace\\src\\working\\selenium\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

without while loop and `next` the code is working fine but when I run the aforementioned code its printing the first page table data 3 times repeatedly and throws the following error:

> Mar 20, 2021 11:21:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
> createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS "Fly Armenia Airways"
> Limited Liability Company Armenia VF  914      "NOVAIR" Limited Liability
> Company   Armenia NG  206      21 Air LLC UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    2I*     681
> 40-Mile Air, Ltd. UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    Q5*          748 Air
> Services  Kenya   H4* 874 874
>
> 2 "Fly Armenia Airways" Limited Liability Company Armenia VF  914
> "NOVAIR" Limited Liability Company    Armenia NG  206      21 Air LLC UNITED
> STATES OF AMERICA 2I*     681  40-Mile Air, Ltd.  UNITED STATES OF
> AMERICA   Q5*          748 Air Services   Kenya   H4* 874 874  "Fly Armenia
> Airways" Limited Liability Company    Armenia VF  914      "NOVAIR" Limited
> Liability Company Armenia NG  206      21 Air LLC UNITED STATES OF
> AMERICA   2I*     681  40-Mile Air, Ltd.  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    Q5*
> 748 Air Services  Kenya   H4* 874 874
>
> 3 Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
> reference: element is not attached to the page document   (Session
> info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088
> (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT
> 10.0.18363 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds For
> documentation on this error, please visit:
> https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-832OS5B', ip:
> '10.122.250.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2' Driver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
> {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false,
> applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false,
> browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.42.591088
> (7b2b2dca23cca0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Lo...},
> cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions:
> {debuggerAddress: localhost:59261}, handlesAlerts: true,
> hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true,
> locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
> nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy:
> normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false,
> setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true,
> unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version:
> 89.0.4389.90, webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: 5064d7cddc475396a421aa6d1639fb5c   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:166)
> at working.Test.scrape(Test.java:41)    at
> working.Test.main(Test.java:21)

How can I print each page table data by clicking `NEXT` button?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Refresh page after clicking Next button each time.
- Declare table_element, tr_collection inside while.
- Declare scrape() with void return and just call scrape() without print.
- Also did some other changes in code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test 
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        openBrowser();
        //System.out.println(scrape());
        scrape();
        closeBrowser();
    }

    private static String table = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[1]";
    private static String tr = table + "/tbody/tr";
    private final static String next = table + "/preceding::a[text()='Next'][1]";
    private final static String yesGotIt = "//body/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-banner \")]/div/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-button-wrapper \")]/button";

    private static void scrape() throws Exception 
    {
        // WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
        // List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

        int count = 1;
        // String rows = "";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(yesGotIt)).click();
        while (count <= 3) {
            //Declare rows here - previous page's data will not repeatedly print
            String rows = "";

            System.out.println(count);

            // Declare WebElement, List here
            WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
            List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

            for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) 
            {
                List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) 
                {
                    rows += tdElement.getText() + "\t";
                }
                rows = rows + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(rows);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click();
            count += driver.findElements(By.xpath(next)).size();
            //System.out.println(count);

            //refresh page to ignore StaleElementReferenceException
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
        }
    }

    private static void openBrowser() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "E:\\eclipse-workspace\\src\\working\\selenium\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static void closeBrowser() 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: This code works fine with first table on the page when I change xPath `"(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[1]";` to `"(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]";` then its repeating only first page.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so everything is still working after changing table variable - look at console print. As visibility is focused on first table, last table's page change is not observeable. To focus on actual table's next button JavascriptExecutor is used and updated the whole code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test 
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        openBrowser();
        //System.out.println(scrape());
        scrape();
        //closeBrowser();
    }

    //private static String table = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[1]";
    private static String table = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]";
    private static String tr = table + "/tbody/tr";
    private final static String next = table + "/preceding::a[text()='Next'][1]";
    private final static String yesGotIt = "//body/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-banner \")]/div/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-button-wrapper \")]/button";

    private static void scrape() throws Exception 
    {
        // WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
        // List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

        int count = 1;
        // String rows = "";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(yesGotIt)).click();
        while (count <= 3) {
            //Declare rows here - previous page's data will not repeatedly print
            String rows = "";

            System.out.println(count);

            // Declare WebElement, List here
            WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
            List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

            for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) 
            {
                List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) 
                {
                    rows += tdElement.getText() + "\t";
                }
                rows = rows + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(rows);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
            
            //scroll to next button
            JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(next));
            je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", we);
            we.click();
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click();
            count += driver.findElements(By.xpath(next)).size();
            //System.out.println(count);

            //refresh page to ignore StaleElementReferenceException
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
        }
    }

    private static void openBrowser() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "E:\\eclipse-workspace\\src\\working\\selenium\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static void closeBrowser() 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```